# Wifi slows to crawl Intel Centrino wireless -N 1000

Tags: 12.10, wireless, drivers, intel-wireless, centrino

I've been experiencing sever bandwidth issues with my laptop and was hoping someone could help me resolve them.

Speedtest.net typically reports my dl rate is ~ 18 Mb, upload ~ 2.5 Mb and ping ~ 20ms, when I'm experiencing a slowdown it's ~ 1. ~1.5, 70, respectively. This slow down only affect my Linux installation, all other computers and my windows partition functions fine. 
My laptop is a lenovo Y570, running Ubuntu 12.10 with 3.9.0-030900rc6-generic kernal, and Windows 7. I was experiencing this issue before while using network-manager and switched to wicd, although there hasn't been any measure improvement

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: [REMOVED]
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.130 firmware=sb latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:f1800000-f180ffff memory:f1810000-f181ffff memory:f1820000-f18207ff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: [REMOVED]
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.9.0-030900rc6-generic firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:58 memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
```

**sudo lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 555M] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57781 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
08:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
09:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
0a:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
0a:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
0a:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
0a:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller (rev 30)
```

**ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:0e:a1:85:79:65  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:859 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:176313 (176.3 KB)  TX bytes:176313 (176.3 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b6:24:f9:b9:3a:46  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:e5:0b:e6:35:86  
          inet addr:192.168.1.66  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:28652 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:29047155 (29.0 MB)  TX bytes:14690621 (14.6 MB)
```

**iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"KendalAndBergman"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: A8:39:44:4E:05:10   
          Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:741   Missed beacon:0
```

**rfkill list**

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

I've already tried the commands below, which although they made a slight change ( less latency and dl rate up 1 mb), I'm not sure if it wasn't just a coincidence.

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the link quality value lower in iwconfig when the bandwith problem happens? Does it happen with the standard distro kernels as well?

Comment: yea, all the above output was taken during bandwidth problems. I haven't tried any other distros on this laptop.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that typically the issues can be resolved for at least a little while by disabling and then enabling wireless, in either software or hardware but the problems typically come back after a few minutes.

Comment: I mean the standard kernels in Ubuntu 12.10, version 3.5.0.x Does the problem persist with them?

Comment: Try putting `eth0` down as well and see if that helps any.  I've seen issues with interference with Intel wireless cards for some reason. `sudo ifconfig eth0 down`

Comment: I haven't tried other kernals, and eth0 down doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Also perhaps worth noting that high load such as torrenting cause the connection to completely die within a few minutes. When this happens bandwidth is about 1 Kb/s - 0 and is only restored after cycling the wireless.